# Using Arrays instead of named route helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Consider the following coding styles:

```
link_to 'Widget', [:admin, widget]
# vs
link_to 'Widget', admin_widget_path(widget)

form_for [:admin, widget]
# vs
form_for widget, :url => admin_widget_path(widget)
```

Which do you prefer and why? I'm mostly interested in *why* you prefer one over the other.

**Update**

Only 1 comment? I'm disappointed :( Was hoping to maybe hear things about performance, conventions, consistency, etc. Seems like StackOverflow has turned into quick off-the-cuff answers in hopes of getting points. What happened to discussions and thought?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the helper method, because I have completion on them, and they read better to me.

I find the array version less communicative (if shorter), and have less IDE support (but YMMV).